# Cannot replace £ with &pound from string

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, str-replace

I have a HTML string containing £ signs, for some reason i'm not able to replace them. I'm assuming this is an encoding issue although i can't work out how. The site is using ISO-8859-1 for its encoding

```
$str = '<span class="price">£89.99</span>';
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($str, 'ISO-8859-1', true)); // outputs ISO-8859-1

echo str_replace(array("£","&pound;"),"",$str); // nothing is removed

echo htmlentities($str); // the entire string is converted, including £ to &pound;
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

should have pointed out i want to replace the £ with `&pound`;  - i had temporarily added `&pound` to the array of items to replace in case it had already been converted

Comment: Everything ok here: `string(10) "ISO-8859-1"
<span class="price">89.99</span>&lt;span class=&quot;price&quot;&gt;&Acirc;&pound;89.99&lt;/span&gt;`

Comment: i appreciate it *should* work :) i guess my question should have been, why would this not work?!

Comment: I just copied and pasted the code you gave, the £ sign is removed on the 3rd line of code.

Comment: Check var_dump(mb_detect_encoding("£", 'ISO-8859-1', true));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a guess but could it be that even thou your website outputs in ISO-8859-1 encoding, your actual *.php files are saved as utf-8?  i don't think that str_replace works correctly with utf-8 strings. To test it try:

```
str_replace(utf8_decode("£"),"&pound;",utf8_decode($str));
```

Yeah, if this works then your *.php files are saved in utf-8 encoding. This means all the string constants are in utf-8. It's probably worth switching default encoding in your IDE to ISO-8859-1

Comment: That is my guess to. Check the encoding of "£".

Comment: I must point out i have no idea how and why this works though

Comment: @seengee your IDE or text editor saves *.php files in utf-8 encoding. When PHP reads the strings in your source code it reads them in the same utf-8 encoding. PHP5 doesn't have full unicode support so some functionality is flawed. Changing settings in your text-editor/IDE to save your source code in ISO-8859-1 encoding will prevent this problems, and you will not need to use utf8_decode()

Comment: @Ivan - i have never even thought of changing that in Netbeans, you're right though. switching to ISO in the Netbeans settings means a standard str_replace works!

Answer (score 1):

```
html_entity_decode(str_replace("&pound;", "", htmlentities($str)));
```

Comment: oops, should have pointed out i want to replace the £ with &pound;

Comment: @seengee then just use htmlentities($str); from Jan's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '<span class="price">£89.99</span>';
echo str_replace("£","&pound;",$str);
```

Output:

```
<span class="price">&pound;89.99</span>
```

Comment: i know that should work, thats where the question comes from! See my note in Ivan's answer for the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = str_replace("£","&pound;",utf8_encode($data));
echo $data;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.